# Both radio buttons getting selected even though name is same (iOS 12.2)

Tags: angular

There is a single select question it can have multiple options. In specially iOS 12.2 version I am facing issue both are getting selected, in Android it works fine.

Please give suggestion. Here is the HTML code:

```
<label class="radio" *ngFor="let option of question.answerOptions">
   <input type="radio" [formControlName]="question.id" [disabled]="disabled" [name]="radio-btn" [value]="option" [(ngModel)]="value">
     <span class="radio-toggle"></span>
     <span class="radio-text">{{ option[label] || option.label }}</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Corrected poor code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Give a unique id to each radio button

```
<label class="radio" *ngFor="let option of question.answerOptions; let i = index">

       <input type="radio" [formControlName]="question.id" [disabled]="disabled" id="radio-btn{{i}}" [value]="option" [(ngModel)]="value">

 <span class="radio-toggle"></span>
     <span class="radio-text">{{ option[label] || option.label }}</span>
</label>
```